# Trying to use cursor.getCount(), cannot resolve symbol getCount()

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-cursor

i am making a android project when i try to use cursor.getCount(); it giving me error:

> cannot resolve symbol getCount();

Here is my code

```
class GetNotesFromDbTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(NoteDetail.this);
    dialog.setTitle("Loading");
    dialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();
}


SQLiteDatabase db = helpers.getReadableDatabase();
String[] projection = {
        NoteContract.FeedEntry._ID,
        NoteContract.FeedEntry.NOTES_TITLE,
        NoteContract.FeedEntry.NOTES_ID,
        NoteContract.FeedEntry.NOTES_BODY,

};

String sortOrder =
        NoteContract.FeedEntry.NOTES_ID + " DESC";

Cursor cursor = db.query(
        NoteContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,  // The table to query
        projection,                               // The columns to return
        null,                                // The columns for the WHERE clause
        null,                            // The values for the WHERE clause
        null,                                     // don't group the rows
        null,                                     // don't filter by row groups
        sortOrder                                 // The sort order
);


if(cursor.getCount()>0) //here i am getting error

{

}
```

I define cursor too, i did not understand why it is not working.

Also,

i tried `if(cursor !=null)`

it is saying to me

> cursor unknown class

Comment: statements go into methods or static blocks.

Comment: i think your code should have compile error. could you post "GetNotesFromDbTask " class full code?

Comment: I solved it.  protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {return null;}  automatically closed itself, because of that cursor did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be inside a method that is inside a class, not on the class level itself.

Previous lines are syntactically valid since they are variable declarations and initialisations. An `if` conditional is not valid on class level.

Answer (score 0):

```
            class GetNotesFromDbTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
      SQLiteDatabase db = helpers.getReadableDatabase();
            String[] projection = {
                    NoteContract.FeedEntry._ID,
                    NoteContract.FeedEntry.NOTES_TITLE,
                    NoteContract.FeedEntry.NOTES_ID,
                    NoteContract.FeedEntry.NOTES_BODY,

            };

            String sortOrder =
                    NoteContract.FeedEntry.NOTES_ID + " DESC";

            Cursor cursor = db.query(
                    NoteContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,  // The table to query
                    projection,                               // The columns to return
                    null,                                // The columns for the WHERE clause
                    null,                            // The values for the WHERE clause
                    null,                                     // don't group the rows
                    null,                                     // don't filter by row groups
                    sortOrder                                 // The sort order
            );


            if(cursor.getCount()>0) //here i am getting error

            {

            }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(NoteDetail.this);
                dialog.setTitle("Loading");
                dialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
                dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.show();
            }

            }  // this line add asynctask class end 

          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            GetNotesFromDbTask  gnfd=new GetNotesFromDbTask ();
            //asynctask run onpre ->onbackground->onpost
gnfd.execute();


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into this problem.

The test should be if(!cursor.moveToFirst())

with invalid cursor, this will return true.

Comment: This doesn't answers the question asked. The problem with the code posted by OP is that he/she did the conditional checking at the class level, but it should be done inside a method.